# Unity freezes for periods of time

Tags: unity, 11.10, ccsm

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity.

Whenever I try to minimize or maximize any application window the UI gets struck for around 45 secs. How do I overcome this other than removing Unity?

I get this after configuring Wallpaper plugin in ccsm.

Update:

Laptop model : HP dv6

Graphics card : nVidia Corporation G86 [GeForce 8400M GS]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: @JorgeCastro added the graphics card info...

Answer (score 2):

Very frequently there's a substantial lag issue if you have an nVidia graphics card. If you don't know what card you have use lspci in terminal.

If you do have it then get into classic and update the driver to the most recent version. The difference is immediately apparent after a quick restart.